# gcc optimized out unused variable when it should not

Tags: c, variables, gcc, optimization

Considering the following code which many comes mostly from Bluedroid stack

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define STREAM_TO_UINT16(u16, p) {u16 = ((uint16_t)(*(p)) + (((uint16_t)(*((p) + 1))) << 8)); (p) += 9;}

void func(uint8_t *param) {
        uint8_t *stream = param;
        uint16_t handle, handle2;
        
        *stream = 5;
        
        STREAM_TO_UINT16(handle, stream);
        STREAM_TO_UINT16(handle2, stream);
        assert(handle);
        assert(handle2);
        
        *stream = 7;
}
```

```
    .file   "opt.c"
    .text
    .align  4
    .global func
    .type   func, @function
func:
    entry   sp, 32
    movi.n  a8, 5
    s8i a8, a2, 0
    movi.n  a8, 7
    s8i a8, a2, 18
    retw.n
    .size   func, .-func
    .ident  "GCC: (crosstool-NG esp-2020r3) 8.4.0"
```

When  it is compiled with NDEBUG, then assert() resolved to nothing and "handle" is optimized out with -O2 or's' or '3' . As a result, the macro is not expanded and the pointer is not incremented.

I know that I can make "handle" volatile as one option to solve the issue and I agree adding variable modification in macros is dangerous, but this is not my code, this is Bluedroid.

Well first, is this borderline a gcc bug and then is there a way to tell gcc to not optimize out unused variable?

Comment: Of course this is not a GCC bug. The assignment to `handle` has no observable effect, so it may be optimized out. What do you think could be accomplished by keeping it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil `handle` may be optimized out, but OP is also claiming that the `(p) += 2` from the macro gets optimized out. That does not look right.

Comment: Everything seems fine to me with the last 4 major version of GCC : https://godbolt.org/z/xo3TsEarc (the same thing applies with `-O3`). `stream` is implicitly incremented by two before doing the write.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: GCC stores to `x+2`, where `x` is the value of `param` when the function starts. As long as that is done, modifications to `param` have no observable effect. If OP is seeing something other than a store to that address, they need to provide a [mre], include a specific GCC version number.

Comment: why do you `typedef unsigned char uint8_t;` when you already `#include <stdint.h>` in the beginning?

Comment: Sorry folks I was not clear. I've changed the example and added the assembly. What seems to me is that the increment to stream is made at the end and is useless

Comment: @EricPostpischil oh, of course, there's no `*` there. You're right.

Answer (score 0):

Oops ... no I just re-read the ISA of the eXtensa and I was wrong, the value of a8 is stored where a2 points, with offset, so this is correct. I need to look somewhere else b/c the core of the problem is that as soon as I set NDEBUG, my bluedroid stacks (this is on esp32) stops working, so I was searching for differences and looking where the compiler was whining (unused variables). Thanks for taking the time to answer.